# Magento 2: Limit the orders for a specific admin user

Tags: magento2, orders, admin-user

I have created an admin user who can upload products, after that if he got an order for this product this will show in order page normally, what I want is to limit the only products that he uploaded (I am keeping track of admin user with his ID by the product attribute), so he will be able to see only his orders.
but here the all orders is showing...

[image]

Comment: 1 order can contain multiple products created by different admin. in that case how you will filter.

Comment: so what would be the logic behind to get the orders

Comment: if still you want to filter it will be illogical.

Comment: how can i filter it?